# Can I have just getters and not setter?

Tags: groovy, default, setter, getter

I am quite new to groovy, and I have found out that by making a field public, groovy provides getters and setters by default. Is there a way to have just the getters but not the setters by default?
The reason behind this is that I have a Builder and I don't want to provide access to the object fields for modification.

Comment: Make the property `final `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the fields `final` and add the `Canonical` transform to get the c'tor created automatically for you.  Or even easier use the [`Immutable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html) transform:

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class A {
    String x
}

def a = new A("x")
assert a.x == "x"
// a.x = "will fail"
// a.setX("will fail")
```

In any case, you should take a look into the [`builder transforms`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/builder/package-summary.html), what they have to offer for your use case.